# How to add Test plan license users to Azure DevOps service Organization?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am using Enterprise Agreement (EA) contract subscription for organization. I have tied my DevOps service organization to a EA subscription.

Let’s assume, I am admin for managing all licenses for my company. 
Now what’s the process looks like to add additional users with specific access level who do not have any Visual Studio licenses?

Specifically, I want to add 10 users with Azure **Test plan** licenses. They do not have any Visual Studio licenses either. So do I just go to **Users** tab in Organization setting and add users and select access level? And will they be granted the specific access level licenses and billed pro-rated on that subscription at the monthly billing?

Or do I have to use **Billing** tab to first purchase the license? And then go to **Users** tab to associate a license I just purchased to my user? All I see when I go to **Billing** tab for adding Test plan license is "Enable trail".

**How do I buy multiple Test Plan license from Billing Tab for EA subscription?**
or Do I have to add a *SKW#*  for specific DevOps Service license to my EA contract?
And then will it show up in the Billing tab of Organization setting associated with EA subscription?

Somehow this license management and adding users process is not concisely explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears that Microsoft has now enabled [user assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-158-update#user-assignment-based-billing-and-default-access-level) based billing from Sept 23, 2019. So now you just add and remove users from Users tab and Microsoft will charge you based on the assignment (Access level) automatically.

Instead of having to increase or decrease the number of paid Basic or Basic + Test Plan licenses your organization has available to assign, now that happens automatically when you add or remove users, or change their access level. This means that you’re never paying for more licenses than you’re using, and it makes automating your access level assignment much easier. For example, you have been able to set up group rules to control what access level is assigned to new users that join your team automatically. However, in the past, these only worked if you had extra licenses you were paying for that weren’t assigned to anyone yet, and if you ran out, the group rule failed. Those type of errors no longer happen, as long as the Azure subscription you use for billing stays active.

Update:
First make sure you have setup billing to a valid and active Azure Subscription. Then you may have to enable Trial Basic+Test plan on Billing Tab and wait for few minutes before you can see Basic+test Plan Access level in User Tab of Organization Setting.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please [accept your solution as the answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0):

> Or do I have to use Billing tab to first purchase the license? And
>   then go to Users tab to associate a license I just purchased to my
>   user? All I see when I go to Billing tab for adding Test plan license
>   is "Enable trail".

You can purchase that in **Billing** page and save that. Then you can add ten user with `Basic+Test Plan` access level in **Users** tab. Check the price [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/).

[image]

More details you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/try-additional-features-vs?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fsecurity-access-billing%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fsecurity-access-billing%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops). Also you may get some help from [Manage paid access for users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/buy-basic-access-add-users?view=azure-devops).

**Note:**

*Assign users Basic or Basic + Test Plans, and they can access Test Plans during the trial. Assigning Basic + Test Plans requires that you set up billing first. But, charges for those users don't start until the trial expires.*